# Seaborn - KDE subplots with hue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

As title mentions I'm trying to create 4 matplotlib subplots, and in each I want to plot a KDE plot hue'd by a column in my dataframe. I have found a way to "kind of" do this, and this is the code:

```
ScoreDiffMinus1 = ScoreMovements.loc[ScoreMovements['ScoreDifference'] == -1]
ScoreDiffMinus2 = ScoreMovements.loc[ScoreMovements['ScoreDifference'] == -2]
ScoreDiffMinus3 = ScoreMovements.loc[ScoreMovements['ScoreDifference'] == -3]
ScoreDiffMinus4 = ScoreMovements.loc[ScoreMovements['ScoreDifference'] == -4]

fg, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize = (20,12.5), sharex=True, sharey=True)

Face1 = sns.FacetGrid(ScoreDiffMinus1, hue="Product")
G1 = Face1.map(sns.kdeplot, 'DateDifference', ax = ax[0,0])

Face2 = sns.FacetGrid(ScoreDiffMinus2, hue="Product")
G2 = Face2.map(sns.kdeplot, 'DateDifference', ax = ax[0,1])

Face3 = sns.FacetGrid(ScoreDiffMinus3, hue="Product")
G3 = Face3.map(sns.kdeplot, 'DateDifference', ax = ax[1,0])

Face4 = sns.FacetGrid(ScoreDiffMinus4, hue="Product")
G4 = Face4.map(sns.kdeplot, 'DateDifference', ax = ax[1,1])
```

The issue with this approach is that I am running both a FacetGrid and Matplotlib subplots, which means I have my 4 charts and below I have 4 empty charts from the FacetGrid. What this also means is that I can't set xlabels, titles etc the same way I would be able to if I was running a simple KDE plot.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I'm missing on something obvious but the approach above isn't really working for me.

Thanks

Comment: You need to pick which way you want to do things: do you want to use matplotlib subplots or do you want to use a facetgrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

p = np.random.choice(["Fan", "Table", "Ball"], size=100)
sd = np.random.randint(-4,0,size=100)
dd = np.random.randint(0,40,size=100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ScoreDifference': sd ,
                   'DateDifference':  dd ,
                   "Product": p})



grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='ScoreDifference', hue="Product", col_order=range(-4,0)[::-1])
grid.map(sns.kdeplot, 'DateDifference')
grid.add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]